# declaring a variable in one file and using it in another

Tags: c

I made 2 files which are different from the program above
one is temp1.h and another is temp2.c to understand how extern is used.
So here is temp1.h

```
#include<stdlib.h>
typedef struct node * bond;
extern int jk;
```

and temp2.c is

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<temp1.h>
struct node {
int data;
};
int main ()
{
bond t1;
t1=(bond)malloc(sizeof(bond));
t1->data=23;
printf("the data is %d\n",t1->data);
jk=0;
printf("The variable jk = %d\n",jk);
}
```

and when I compile these as
`cc -I ./ temp2.c`  then I get

```
/tmp/ccdeJCat.o: In function `main':
temp2.c:(.text+0x3c): undefined reference to `jk'
temp2.c:(.text+0x46): undefined reference to `jk'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I had declared jk in temp1.h as an extern int so why can I not initialize it in temp2.c?

Comment: This is basically the same question as the [previous one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4274190/warning-in-extern-declaration).  If you need to clarify, please edit the question.

Comment: +1 to Matthew Flaschen, Why can't the previous question be edited?

Comment: See [SO 1433204](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433204/what-are-extern-variables-in-c) for an explanation of how to define and use global variables in C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int jk;
```

The above declaration must be made somewhere in the code. Also, `jk` must be global.

Answer (score 2):

There's no object file you've linked against that *doesn't* have it declared `extern`, so there's no definition.

Answer (score 0):

instead of #include <temp1.h>

replace with #include "temp1.h"

Comment: The angle brackets are for files in a particular hierarchy of the system (typically system headers). The quoted filenames are relative to the current directory.